# The instance of an object vs the reference of an object

Tags: c#, reference, instance

When assigning a variable to other variable when the instance is assigned when the reference is assigned?

For example;

```
Method(int a) 
{

}
int b=3;
Method(b);
```

takes an instance of b and the value of b is not affected if it is not used with ref keyword.

But

```
 Method(TcpClient client)
    {

    }
    TcpClient tcp1=.....;

Method(tcp1);
```

I think here we do not need a ref keyword since the reference of tcp1 is already used, meaning tcp1 will be affected inside the method, since the reference of it is assigned although I did not use the ref keyword.

How can we know when the instance is assigned, when the reference of the object is assigned?

I learnt this thing.What about this?

```
            TcpClient tcp1 = new TcpClient();
            tcp1.Connect(System.Net.IPAddress.Loopback, 5354);
            TcpClient tcp2 = tcp1;

            tcp2=new TcpClient();
            tcp2.Connect(System.Net.IPAddress.Loopback, 5354);
```

Here tcp1 and tcp2 are real two different instances which is connected to the same endpoint. Which tcpclient gets the data? Is this dangerous?

Comment: The difference is that `int` is a value type and `TcpClient` is a reference type. Please read up on those topics.

Comment: You know it from looking at the method declaration, easy peasy.  Using *ref* on a parameter of a reference type is not often correct, it would have to be a method that creates a new instance of the type.  Even then you'd almost always favor using the return value of the method to return the new object reference.

Comment: C# says string is a reference type. But when I use it in a method its value is not changed. It wants a ref keyword. Why?

Comment: @MehmetErkol Because your parameter is a reference to some string somewhere. When you assign a new value to it, it becomes a reference to a different string somewhere else. The original string is still whatever it was. You're not changing a property of the string the local reference points to; you're just pointing the reference to something else. Please read up on value and reference types. You need to read the documentation, then it will be more clear.

Comment: I was very confused at first but I think I am okey right now. Topic is hard to understand I think. Are there any counter example that is a reference type but acts as value type somehow other than string and object types?